# In what circumstances are instance variables declared as '_var' in 'use fields' private?

Tags: perl, oop, field, private-members

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the `fields` pragma, which I find [poorly documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/fields.html), regarding fields prefixed with underscores. This is what the documentation has to say about it:

> Field names that start with an underscore character are made private to the class and are not visible to subclasses. Inherited fields can be overridden but will generate a warning if used together with the -w switch.

This is not consistent with its actual behavior, according to my test, below. Not only are `_`-prefixed fields visible within a subclass, they are visible within foreign classes as well (unless I don't get what 'visible' means). Also, directly accessing the restricted hash works fine.

Where can I find more about the behavior of the `fields` pragma, short of going at the source code?

```
{
    package Foo;
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use fields qw/a _b __c/;

    sub new {
        my ( $class ) = @_;
        my Foo $self = fields::new($class);
        $self->a = 1; $self->b = 2; $self->c = 3;
        return $self;
    }

    sub a : lvalue { shift->{a}   }
    sub b : lvalue { shift->{_b}  }
    sub c : lvalue { shift->{__c} }
}
{
    package Bar;
    use base 'Foo';
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my $o = Bar->new;
    print Dumper $o; ##$VAR1 = bless({'_b' => 2, '__c' => 3, 'a' => 1}, 'Foo');

    $o->a = 4; $o->b = 5; $o->c = 6;
    print Dumper $o; ##$VAR1 = bless({'_b' => 5, '__c' => 6, 'a' => 4}, 'Foo');

    $o->{a} = 7; $o->{_b} = 8; $o->{__c} = 9;
    print Dumper $o; ##$VAR1 = bless({'_b' => 8, '__c' => 9, 'a' => 7}, 'Foo');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coincidentally enough, I happen to have a test script in `~/codescraps/fields/test.pl` dated from two years ago when I experimented with answering exactly this same question. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

{
   package Foo;
   use fields qw(foo bar _Foo_private);
   use private qw(_really_private);
   sub new {
       my Foo $self = shift;
       unless (ref $self) {
           $self = fields::new($self);
           $self->{_Foo_private} = "this is Foo's secret";
       }
       $self->{foo} = 10;
       $self->{bar} = 20;
       return $self;
   }
}

my $foo = Foo->new;
$foo->{foo} = 42;

# this will generate an error: field does not exist
#$foo->{zap} = 42;

print "_Foo_private: " . $foo->{_Foo_private} . "\n";
$foo->{_Foo_private} = 1;
print "_Foo_private: " . $foo->{_Foo_private} . "\n";

print "_really_private: " . $foo->{_really_private} . "\n";
$foo->{_really_private} = 1;
print "_really_private: " . $foo->{_really_private} . "\n";

print Dumper($foo);

# subclassing
{
   package Bar;
   use base 'Foo';
   use fields qw(baz _Bar_private);        # these fields not shared with Foo
   sub new {
       my $class = shift;
       my $self = fields::new($class);
       $self->SUPER::new();                # init base fields
       $self->{baz} = 10;                  # init own fields
       $self->{_Bar_private} = "this is Bar's secret";
       return $self;
   }
}

my $bar = Bar->new;
# these work fine
$bar->{foo} = 1;
$bar->{bar} = 1;
$bar->{_Bar_private} = 1;

# this will not work - underscored fields are not visible to children
$bar->{_Foo_private} = 1;
```

And when I run your code, I get the error:

```
No such pseudo-hash field "_b" at test2.pl line 16.
```

(line 16 is the definition for sub b.)  What architecture are you running this on?  Objects using the fields pragma aren't simple blessed hashrefs -- they are blessed arrayrefs, e.g. when I modify your constructor to look like this:

```
sub new {
    my ( $class ) = @_;
    my Foo $self = fields::new($class);
    $self->{a} = 1; $self->{_b} = 2; $self->{__c} = 3;
    print "I look like: ", Data::Dumper::Dumper($self);
    return $self;
}
```

I see:

```
I look like: $VAR1 = bless( [
                 bless( {
                          'a' => 1
                        }, 'pseudohash' ),
                 1,
                 2,
                 3
               ], 'Bar' );
```

---

As a postscript, I feel obliged to point out that the [fields](http://perldoc.perl.org/fields.html) pragma, and the [base](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html) pragma that goes with it, are both deprecated and one is strongly urged to avoid using them.  Nowadays, if you're looking to construct a nice OO module with accessors, one would either use [Class::Accessor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Accessor) or go directly to [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm running x86_64, debian and perl 5.10. I have to point out, as well, that as far as I know, `fields` is not deprecated at all. However, since 5.9, its implementation stopped using pseudo-hashes in favor of restricted hashes. And I, too, have a copy of Conways' OO Perl; I certainly know about the alternatives to 'fields' and 'base'. As I said, I just want to understand the pragmas, and the documentation is lacking.

Comment: @Pedro: aye, they'll be available for quite some time, but not really supported anymore; I actually asked a question here about `fields` myself, a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168644/why-is-the-fields-pragma-incompatible-with-multiple-inheritance-in-perl -- and got the same "use Moose instead" replies. :)